# Polymer 2.0 app location query params is giving the name of the page rather than actual GET parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer-2.x

I have created a project with Polymer and NodeJS. In the second page when I am trying to get data from my NodeJS server with **iron-ajax** I am passing the url as http://localhost:3000/images.html?category=123. But in the NodeJS server i am getting images.html as the parameter in **req** object.My Polymer element looks like this where I am making the API call

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" query-params="{{queryParams}}"></app-location>
        <iron-ajax
            id="requestCats"
            url="http://localhost:3000/{{queryParams.category}}"
            handle-as="json"
            debounce-rate="5000"
            on-response="handleResponse">
        </iron-ajax>
```

**images.html** is the page where this element is residing. and in my NodeJS server I am trying like this:

```
app.get('/:cat',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('/GET images');
  console.log('got cat parameter '+req.params.cat);
  ...
}
```

in the console the above is printing **got cat parameter images.html**

what can be wrong in this? I went through some other answers.Some suggested to use **nebula-location** but that did not work also.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
app.get('/images.html/:category',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('/GET images');
  console.log('got cat parameter '+req.params.cat);
  ...
}
```

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html